# Enable Error Reporting on open shift

Tags: php, openshift

I am using Red Hat's Openshift online and I am building a PHP app with the PHP 5.3 cartridge and the PHPMyAdmin4.0 cartridge.

How can I enable error reporting on the webpage if an error exists in the PHP code?

I can’t seem the find the option in PHPMyAdmin and the following lines of PHP code did not work.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: phpmyadmin has nothing to do with displaying php errors on your website.  Have you tried checking your log files in ~/app-root/logs? Or you can try using the rhc tail command to view your log files.

Comment: Thanks, I used tail on the log file and it helped.  I think this should help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php